# Why is my jquery object changing context?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-context

I am comparing on mousedown event two elements but they are false because of the context property:

```
console.log(this, opt.selectedNode);
[circle, prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: undefined, jquery: "2.0.3", constructor: function, init: function…]
[circle, prevObject: x.fn.x.init[3], context: document, jquery: "2.0.3", constructor: function, init: function…]
```

This is what I do on mousedown:

```
$("circle").ondrag({
    start:function(){
        //this is a jQuery object
        console.log(this==opt.selectedNode); //true the first time, false the second time it's executed
        console.log(this[0]==opt.selectedNode[0]); //always true
        if (this==opt.selectedNode) { //select other node
            $(".selectedNode").removeNSClass("selectedNode");
            if (!point.isFirst()) {
                opt.selectedNode = $("circle").bydata('point',pointarray[pointarray.indexOf(point)-1]).addNSClass("selectedNode"); //if there is a node before
            } else if (!point.isLast()) {
                opt.selectedNode = $("circle").bydata('point',pointarray[pointarray.indexOf(point)+1]).addNSClass("selectedNode"); //if there is a node after
            } else opt.selectedNode = null; //last point, select nothing
        }
    }
});
```

Why the context changed?

Comment: One jQuery object is not equal to another one, they are two different objects even if they contain the same DOM elements, however comparing plain JS DOM elements will work

Comment: But they are supposed to be the same.

Comment: So every selector return a different object?

Comment: Indeed -> http://jsfiddle.net/zV52E/

Comment: But DOM nodes are not plain objects, so they can be compared -> http://jsfiddle.net/zV52E/1/

Comment: but @adeneo `this` within the handler is a DOM node, not jQuery object. Your first fiddle compares elements wrapped in `$()`

Comment: And so is the OP, at least according to the two lines which looks like they are from a console log.

Comment: Yes in my example this is a jQuery object. I'm sorry for the confusion, but it's not actually a mousedown, I'll correct that.

Comment: @adeneo yup...wasn't paying attention to what `op.selectedNode` was.... would work with `this==opt.selectedNode[0]` assuming only one `circle` in page